# How to get label value which is assigned or set client side by jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm unable to get `asp:label` value on server side which is set client-side in jQuery.

The small example is as below:

```
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        $("#<%=prd1.ClientID %>").text("L1001");
    });
```

Now I want it back in asp textbox by clicking another button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Test.text=prd1.text;
}
```

I'm trying to get back value of “prd1” in textbox “Test” but failed.

Any idea why?

Comment: There is no value associated with label. Use a hidden field instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no value associated with label. Use a asp hidden field instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        $("#<%=hidden.ClientID %>").val("L1001");

    });    

protected void Button1_Click( Object  sender, EventArgs e) 
{
      Test.text=hidden.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using asp:label you can do is use a standard label tag and put runat="server" in that tag like

```
<label runat="server" id="temp_lbl"></label>
```

In jquery

```
$("#<%=temp_lbl.ClientID%>").html('Your Data Here');
```

In C#

```
string data = temp_lbl.Value;
```